# Which is better, baking in glass or metal?

Tags: baking, glass

How does baking in glass differ from 
Baking in metal?

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question because "better" is subjective and could mean pretty much anything.

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/baking-in-glass-loaf-pan

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24769/baking-time-difference-in-pyrex-versus-metal

Comment: There is no "better", the choice depends on what you are baking, and in what kind of oven. And the difference in result between a given metal pan and a given glass pan can be smaller than the difference between two metal pans made from different metals with different thickness and coating.

Answer (score 1):

Because glass is an insulator, it takes longer to heat up, but then stays at the temprature longer. Metal heats up quicker but also doesn't stay warm for as long a time. Here are several interesting links that are helpful for deciding what to pick for each situation.

> [chow.com:](http://www.chow.com/food-news/53759/does-it-matter-whether-you-use-a-glass-or-metal-baking-dish/) Rushing says glass is best for foods like cakes, which
>   bake for a relatively long time at lower temperatures. As in a thick
>   cast iron pan, cornbread baked in glass will brown more evenly than if
>   you use a thin metal dish. However, glass bakeware cannot be made in
>   large sizes and is generally unavailable with a nonstick
>   coating—Teflon is very hard to apply to glass. Other disadvantages of
>   glass are that it is more expensive and much heavier than metal, and
>   it can shatter if its temperature changes too quickly.

> [yumsugar.com:](http://www.yumsugar.com/Glass-Bakeware-vs-Metal-Bakeware-6512749) According to Lauren Chattman, author of The Baking
>   Answer Book, clear glass, much like dark metal, absorbs heat, making
>   it ideal for crisp-crusted pies but much less so for bar cookies,
>   quick breads, and fruit crisps, which can easily become burnt.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely one of those "don't believe everything you read" subjects, which makes ehow especially bad.

Comment: Thx for the input, I removed the ehow link. @TFD