# Can I use a china oven dish to make a sponge cake?

Tags: baking

I want to make an ordinary sponge cake.  The recipe says I need to use a metal cake tin.  Can I use an (ovenproof) china oven dish instead?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://www.amazon.com/HIC-Lasagna-Pan-White-2-5-Inch/dp/B0006BDCZ8/ref=sr_1_13?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1436785114&sr=1-13&keywords=ceramic+bakeware)?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is just fine to bake a cake in a pan like the [one we talked about in comments](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006BDCZ8). A pan of that type *may* stick a bit more than a metal pan, so you might find ["cake release"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44681/how-to-line-this-cake-pan-with-parchment-paper/44692#44692) to be of benefit.

It's unlikely that you will have any problems at all, but read Aaronut's answer [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7693/should-i-be-able-to-make-a-tarte-tatin-in-a-glass-dish?rq=1).